# Numeric input validation in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to validate an input for Account number in php form. It should contain 8 numbers and '-' optionally. If there is '-' - it should be ignored. 
After pressing the Submit button, the warning message suppose to be displayed above the form in case input is invalid.

Please help.

This is what I got so far, but I'm  not sure if this is correct and don't know how to display a warning message above the form.

```
$acctnum= "$acctnum";

if(empty($acctnum)){
  echo "You did not enter an account number, please re-enter"; }

else if(!preg_match("\-^[0-9]{8}", $acctnum)){
  echo "Your account number can only contain eight numbers. Please re-enter."; }
```

Thank you!

Comment: That's not a valid regex, you're missing delimiters.

Comment: Just one "-" or several of them?

Comment: Can you guarantee that all your accounts will have exactly eight digits in the future?

Comment: the condition of an assignment is that account number has to have exactly 8 digits

Answer (score 2):

You don't appear to be trying. No documentation or tutorial will tell you to make a Regex like that. For starters, where are the delimiters? Why is `-` escaped when it's outside a character class and therefore has no special meaning? What is that `^` doing there?

This should do it:

```
$acctnum = str_replace("-","",$acctnum);
if( !preg_match("/^\d{8}$/",$acctnum)) echo "Error...";
```

Comment: This will strip multiple `-`, not allow just one. Might be better to use an assertion here. But OP possibly just meant optional at the start(?)

Comment: Thank you! It should strip multiple '-'.

Comment: Kolink, thank you! I actually tried many other options. The one I wrote is just one of them. I didn't think about str_replace(), didn't use delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Since regex are quite expensive I'd go like that instead:

```
$acctnum = (int) $acctnum; // this automatically ignore the '-'
if ($acctnum < 0) $acctnum = -$acctnum;
$digits = ($acctnum == 0) ? log10($acctnum) + 1 : 1;
if ($digits === 8) { ... }
```

Comment: I don't think we will have performance issues with the regex for this simple task. And it would be more readable than your code. And what about leading zeros?

Comment: @yunzen, Since no one told me that there could be any and considering that `$acctnum` seems a counting integer this solution is faster. If it's not the OP solution at least I'll leave it here for future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

Split the task in two. First get rid of the "-" with `str_replace` and then check for the numbers.

```
$match = preg_match("/^\d{8}$/", str_replace("_", "", $str));
if ($match > 0) {
    // Correct
} else {
    // incorrect
}
```